# Why "No module named 'mysql.connector'; 'mysql' is not a package" even if I already installed this module successfully in Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, mysql-connector

I want to connect MySQL to Python in Ubuntu.
And I try to know that I need to install mysql-connector first.
So I tried following cmd to do it:

```
pip3 install mysql.connector
```

And I also try `pip3 list | grep mysql` to check if it's installed successfully. Of course, everything is OK.
But, when I try `python` and `import mysql.connector`, the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql.connector'; 'mysql' is not a package` is presented.

After check some infomation from network, I alse installed some other module as below:

```
pip3 install mysql-connector-python
pip3 install mysql-connector-python-rf
```

But, the error is still...
I think there must be a basic error that I have, but I do't know what it's.
Please help, thanks.

Comment: Are you 100% certain that `pip` installed into the same python version/environment that you're using to run this script?

Comment: yes, actually I also tried to install the above module by `pip`. And I also check the version of pip version, it's OK.

Comment: Do you have a local file of your own named `mysql.py`?

Comment: yes, just now I tried to change the file name. AMAZING, the error is gone! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With @John Gorden's hint, I found that I can't name the Python file as `mysql.py`. Just changing to another name fixed the issue.